# Store the return string to a variable from zenity

Tags: bash, zenity

I am using Zenity tool to pop-up an entry dialog box. But how can i store the value entered into the text box to a variable ? Now, the string is being printed onto the console itself. I want it to be stored into a variable to process it !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24474286/1030675

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
inputStr=$(zenity --entry --title="My Title" --text="My Text:")
```

to show the content of the variable again you can use this:

```
zenity --info --title="My Title" --text="Your input was: $inputStr"
```

(Where `$inputStr` is the variable in which value form `zenity --entry` will be stored. You can get its value via `echo $inputStr`)

Comment: @Glutanimate are you sure the additional double quotes are required in this case?

Comment: Yes, otherwise the variable assignment might fail if zenity returns a string containing whitespace.

Comment: I've tested it with whitespaces, there was no problem. Can you give a example which will fail please.

Comment: Interesting. I'm not on my PC right now but as soon as I am I'll give it a try and get back to you.

Comment: Looks like you were right: Variable assignments are the one case where command substitutions don't have to be quoted (see [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/118433) and [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4910) for more information). I guess I just got into the habit of quoting everything in order to avert unforeseen word splitting and globbing. Sorry for the edit.  Please feel free to revert it.